# How do I add a filter to return values less than $10,000,000 in this Excel Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table, filtering, conditional-formatting

I am trying to follow along with my instructor on this lesson on Pivot Tables but they are using Google Sheets while I am trying to use Microsoft Excel.  In the example, we entered the fields in the first picture below.[example of pivot table fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl7u6.jpg)

With all that is done, I am supposed to add a filter that will allow me to only pull box office revenue of less than $10,000,000 but when I try to click the drop down menu, there is no area for me to add a filter condition or rule. [picture of drop down filter for Revenue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QVPQ.jpg)

Is there a way to do add a filter condition/rule in Microsoft Excel or is this only possible in Google Sheets?

P.S. This example is from a Google Coursera course and I am trying to master both Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel; however, the examples and steps the instructor gives is for Google Sheets.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try shifting Box Office Revenue to the Values section and applying a Value Filter.

[Screenshot of Value Filter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkUb4.png)

[Screenshot of Value Filter 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbbl6.png)